# (How) can I pass POST arguments from one cherrypy page class to another?

Tags: post, cherrypy

Following Cherrypy's [tutorial](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyTutorial#ReceivingdatafromHTMLforms), it seems fairly easy to receive data from a form "within" a page class. Now, i have tried to pass the arguments to *another* page class's index page like the following:

In my root index page I have the following form:

```
<form action="otherpage" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="arg1"> 
    ... 
</form>
```

while the receiving page's class is like:

```
class OtherPage:
   def index(self, arg1=None):
      return arg1
```

and it is mounted like

```
root.otherpage = Otherpage()
```

It always shows a blank page, regardless of what I put in the form, so I guess it doesn't get the parameter "arg" passed correctly. Do you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried CherryPy for the first time today and encountered exactly the same problem. I think that *Otherpage* isn't matched correctly because the resulting URI lacks a trailing slash.

Try

```
<form action="otherpage/" method="post">
...
```

Answer (score 3):

When you submit a request for 'otherpage', then CherryPy does attempt to use your Otherpage.index method to handle the request. However, there are two things happening:

1. By default, the [trailing slash Tool](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/cptools.html#cherrypy.lib.cptools.trailing_slash) is on, with the following defaults: `trailing_slash(missing=True, extra=False, status=None, debug=False)`. This means that, if you request the URI `otherpage?arg1=foo`, which is missing a trailing slash, then CherryPy will add the trailing slash and redirect the client to request `otherpage/?arg1=foo` instead. Note that (because the 'extra' arg is False by default) the reverse is not true: `otherpage/` will not redirect to `otherpage`.
2. There's an additional wrinkle, however, because the request is POST and not GET. CherryPy raises a 303 or 302 redirect (depending on which version of HTTP your client supports) and that's probably not what you want for redirecting POST. See http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cperror.html#redirecting-post for the full discussion.

You should either:

1. add the trailing slash in your HTML if you can,
2. set `tools.trailing_slash.missing = False` in config (in which case I believe the index method will just serve the resource without a redirect, or
3. supply a more appropriate "status" argument to the trailing slash Tool if you have control over client behavior.